# Map unrelated input field to BackBone View

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have this BackBone View:

```
window.GDataTableView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'Added', 'Removed' );

        notifications.bind('add',    this.Added );
        notifications.bind('remove', this.Removed );

        Entry.bind('change:Rotation', this.Triangle);

    },
    events: {
      'keypress #my_input_text_box' : "foo"
    },
    foo: function(){
      alert('bar');
    },
...
..
.
```

It is a fairly simple view, but I want ot assign a keypress event in my input field. It is just a text field located somewhare in the page. Now nothing happens when I press a key in the input field. No alert no nothing.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `events` object is scoped to the current view, so it isn't binding to the input you want (since it isn't in the view). Instead, do

```
initialize: function() {
    // your original code

    $("#my_input_text_box").on("keypress", this.foo);
},
```

In other words, you define the event listener when the view instanciates itself.

Depending on your use case, you might need to handle unbinding the event when the view is destroyed.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, within `on` the `this` value will evaluate to `$("#my_input_text_box")`. Also it should be `foo` and not `foo()`: we provide a reference to a function (or alternatively an anonymous function), which will be executed as the callback. If we passed `self.foo()` the result of the `foo()` execution would be defined as the callback, which isn't what we want.

Comment: Oops, you're right: got mixed up with using an anonymous function! Updated my answer...